# FIDO2 for SSH login on Linux Server

Tags: ssh, fido, fido-u2f

To establish an SSH connection between my PC (Linux) and server (Linux) I have to enter the password of the user.

```
ssh USER@<IP-Address>
```

Now I want to replace the password with FIDO2. For this I have executed the following commands on my PC and followed the instructions.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -O resident -O application=ssh:YourTextHere -f ~/.ssh/id_mykey_sk`
```

and

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_mykey_sk.pub USER@<IP-Address>
```

Now I have the problem when I try to establish the SSH connection it still asks for the password instead of the FIDO2 stick. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that when I run the commands

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

and

```
ssh-add -K
```

it works as expected.

Establish a connection to my server via

```
ssh USER@<IP-Address>
```

will now work with the FIDO2 key.